# How to dynamically add django objects to a queryset

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, model, django-queryset

This is my models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):
     title = models.CharField(max_length=100) #The title of the article

     # This is to count the number of users who have viewed the article
     viewed_user = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='viewed_user',blank=True)
```

I'm trying to add the logic in the views.py in that when a user visits the particular article, if the user is not in the viewed_user list, that user is added there.

This is what I have tried in the views.py

```
    article = get_object_or_4040(Article,id=id)
    if user in article.viewed_user.get_queryset():
        print("User has already viewed the article")
    else:
        article.viewed_user.create(user=user) # THrows an error
```

but I have gotten very many types of errors when I tried, update, create, set, append ....

Any help would be appreciated THANKS.

Comment: It will be easier if you include a full reproducible code, and the exacts error you are getting.

Comment: Everything else is working, Just that part which is to add a user object to the viewed_user list when that user opens the article

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have figured it out. The main issue was this error

Direct assignment to the reverse side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use viewed_user.set() instead.

so what I did was use add. For instance in my problem above in the views.py

```
 class Article(View):
     def get(self,request,id=None):
         article = get_object_or_404(Article,id=id)
         user = self.request.user
         if user in article.viewed_user.all():
            print('user in viewed_user')
         else:
            article.viewed_user.add(user) #The updated Code
```

that now works for me. I hope it will someday help someone. Peace